# AES CBC No padding gives extra characters in decrypt JAVa

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt using AES/CBC/NoPadding in JAVA. I did the encryption in both JAVA and PHP using (mcrypt) and got the same result, using the same key and iv. However, when I try to decrypt in JAVA, I get the word correctly but always with extra characters. I read other questions and found that I need to add padding. So I added Padding5 but got the same result. Anyways, I need it without padding because that is how it works in PHP. Any help is appreciated. My code is below and the result is here:[image: result is in image[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSs0v.png)

```
public class RijndaelCrypt {


     //private String key = "2a4e2471c77344b3bf1de28ab9aa492a444abc1379c3824e3162664a2c2b811d";
    private static String iv = "beadfacebadc0fee";
    private static String hashedKey = "6a2dad9f75b87f5bdd365c9de0b9c842";
    private static Cipher cipher;


    public static String decrypt(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {

     SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(hashedKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
     IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] decryptedVal = cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);
            return new String(decryptedVal);              

    }

      public static String encryptNew(String data) throws Exception {

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();

            byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int plaintextLength = dataBytes.length;
            if (plaintextLength % blockSize != 0) {
                plaintextLength = plaintextLength + (blockSize - (plaintextLength % blockSize));
            }

            byte[] plaintext = new byte[plaintextLength];
            System.arraycopy(dataBytes, 0, plaintext, 0, dataBytes.length);

            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(hashedKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);

         }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String data = "Hello";


        System.out.println("New Decrypted: " + RijndaelCrypt.decrypt(RijndaelCrypt.encryptNew(data)));
        System.out.println("New Encryption: " + RijndaelCrypt.encryptNew(data));
         }

   }
```

Comment: Are you saying that in PHP even if you specify no padding, the extra bytes are removed automagically? Because you don't need padding only if you're encrypting data divisible by blocksize, otherwise you do need to get rid of the extra bytes somehow.

Comment: I am not using Padding in PHP and it works without removing any extra bytes.. also both encryption results are the same in PHP and JAVA

Comment: Well it shouldn't work, if you really are using the no padding option. Padding is required to know which bytes are "extra", so it's more likely that  you're actually using padding in PHP without really knowing.

Comment: Your code also seems to implement your own "padding". Which is unnecessary, a bad idea, and probably the root cause of your problems. Not to mention [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) being an obsolete way to go anyway.

Comment: Also mentioned in the link is that mcrypt uses "null padding" by default, so your claim was wrong to start with.

Comment: @Kayaman PHP / mcrypt uses zero padding of 0..15 bytes. So the "own padding" should actually be compatible with PHP. PHP simply doesn't show zero bytes within a string, and often the zero bytes are `rstrip`-ed off as well.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so what do you think the issue is here ?

Comment: Remove the zero bytes at the right hand size of the `decryptedVal`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes you are right .. I thought of the same thing and I am trying to do it now .. I hope it works .. I will update you

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you it works!!!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you can post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP mcrypt wrapper (or underlying mcrypt library) pads with zero bytes up to the block length (zero to 15 padding bytes, if 16 is the block size of the cipher). After that the blocks are encrypted by the cipher.

When decrypting in Java you need to manually remove any zero bytes from the right hand side of the plaintext after decryption using `NoPadding`. The zero valued padding bytes can of course be seen when hex-encoding the decrypted plaintext. However when outputting a string the zero bytes are either left out or converted to a replacement character (depending on the character set and terminal).

Note that the PHP zero padding has one big drawback: if the plaintext ends with one or more zero valued bytes it could be stripped from the decrypted plaintext by any unpadding routine. This is why PKCS#7 padding (which pads 1 to 16 bytes) should be preferred.

Also note that PHP actually needs `rtrim("\0")` to remove the zero bytes itself; mcrypt just leaves them there, but they generally won't be printed.

---

Note that Bouncy Castle crypto libraries also has `ZeroPadding` as option. However, this is zero padding of 1 to 16 bytes (i.e. it always pads/unpads) so it is *incompatible* with the padding defined used by PHP mcrypt and may fail if the size of the plaintext can be divided by the block size of the cipher.